# Inference on HuggingFace pipeline on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am performing inference using a HuggingFace [pipeline](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.24.0/src/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py#L466). As an example take the code below

```py
from transformers import pipeline

summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn", device=0)
    
ARTICLE = """INSERT THE ARTICLE YOU WANT TO SUMMARIZE"""
print(summarizer(ARTICLE, max_length=130, min_length=30, do_sample=False))
```

The argument `device=0` means that the inference is carried out on a cuda device. If I have multiple GPUs available on my machine, is there a way to perform this inference in a distributed fashion so that all GPUs are utilised instead of just one, to reduce inference time?

Answer (score 0):

You can read [Distributed inference with multiple GPUs](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/training/distributed_inference) with using [accelerate](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/index) which is library designed to make it easy to train or run `inference` across distributed setups.

> To begin, create a Python file and initialize an
> accelerate.PartialState to create a distributed environment; your
> setup is automatically detected so you don’t need to explicitly define
> the rank or world_size. Move the DiffusionPipeline to
> distributed_state.device to assign a GPU to each process.
>
> Now use the split_between_processes utility as a context manager to
> automatically distribute the prompts between the number of processes.

```
from accelerate import PartialState
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline

pipeline = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True
)
distributed_state = PartialState()
pipeline.to(distributed_state.device)

with distributed_state.split_between_processes(["a dog", "a cat"]) as prompt:
    result = pipeline(prompt).images[0]
    result.save(f"result_{distributed_state.process_index}.png")
```

> Use the --num_processes argument to specify the number of GPUs to use,
> and call accelerate launch to run the script:

```
 accelerate launch run_distributed.py --num_processes=2
```